# Jenkins pipeline error: Could not find credentials matching

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've a simple Jenkins pipeline which will pull a docker image (from a private registry)and execute command, I'm failing to understand as despite providing credential ID, pipeline fails with error message `ERROR: Could not find credentials matching docker-cred`

Pipeline:

```
pipeline 
{
    agent 
    {
        docker { 
                 image "xxxxxxx/dotnet:latest"
                 registryUrl 'xxxxxxx'
                 registryCredentialsId "docker-cred"
                 reuseNode true
               }
    } 
    stages 
    {
        stage('Test') 
        { 
            steps 
            {
                sh 'dotnet --version' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credentials added:

[image]

Comment: did you try with single quotes?  'docker-cred'

Comment: verify if the credentials type is supported by the plugin

Comment: I did try with single quotes too, but no luck. Yeah, I need to check if credentials type is supported by the plugin.

Comment: There are some weird situations where the pipeline should have access to the credentials, but will not actually have access. You may want to try different variations on the credential settings.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry) you need to use "Username/Password" credentials type:

> For a Docker Registry which requires authentication, add a "Username/Password" Credentials item from the Jenkins home page and use the Credentials ID as a second argument to withRegistry():
> ...

Comment: How do I know what type a credentials item is by just looking at it? This may well be the cause for the same error for our build, but the error message unhelpfully just says it "couldn't find" it. If it found it with the wrong type, the error message really should say that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me, after moving the credential to the global domain, the problem resolved.